# Cannot install software

Tags: command-line, apt

I am currently switching over my VPS hosting and I keep encountering this error on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, The error I am getting is `needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`
I have tried about everything on the internet and even installing a newer kernel.

Complete output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail
  libnginx-mod-stream libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2 nginx-common nginx-core
Suggested packages:
  fcgiwrap nginx-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter libnginx-mod-mail
  libnginx-mod-stream libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2 nginx nginx-common nginx-core
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/696 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,395 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-common.
(Reading database ... 160422 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-nginx-common_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-common (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-geoip2.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libnginx-mod-http-geoip2_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-image-filter.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libnginx-mod-http-image-filter_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-image-filter (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-mail.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libnginx-mod-mail_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-mail (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-stream.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libnginx-mod-stream_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-stream (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2.
Preparing to unpack .../6-libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2 (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx-core.
Preparing to unpack .../7-nginx-core_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx-core (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nginx.
Preparing to unpack .../8-nginx_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) ...
Setting up nginx-common (1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) ...
chown: invalid group: ‘root:adm’
dpkg: error processing package nginx-common (--configure):
 installed nginx-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter:
 libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter depends on nginx-common (= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package nginx-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-http-geoip2:
 libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 depends on nginx-common (= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package nginx-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2:
 libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2 depends on nginx-common (= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package nginx-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx-core:
 nginx-core depends on libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter (= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter is not configured yet.
 nginx-core depends on libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 (= 1.18.0-6uNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                        No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                          No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                                                        buntu14.1); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-http-geoip2 is not configured yet.
 nginx-core depends on libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2 (= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2 is not configured yet.
 nginx-core depends on nginx-common (= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package nginx-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package nginx-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-mail:
 libnginx-mod-mail depends on nginx-common (= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package nginx-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-mail (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nginx:
 nginx depends on nginx-core (<< 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1.1~) | nginx-full (<< 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1.1~) | nginx-light (<< 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1.1~) | nginx-extras (<< 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1.1~); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.
 nginx depends on nginx-core (>= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) | nginx-full (>= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) | nginx-light (>= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1) | nginx-extras (>= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package nginx-core is not configured yet.
  Package nginx-full is not installed.
  Package nginx-light is not installed.
  Package nginx-extras is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nginx (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-http-image-filter:
 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter depends on nginx-common (= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package nginx-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-http-image-filter (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnginx-mod-stream:
 libnginx-mod-stream depends on nginx-common (= 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1); however:
  Package nginx-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libnginx-mod-stream (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36.1-4build1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nginx-common
 libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter
 libnginx-mod-http-geoip2
 libnginx-mod-stream-geoip2
 nginx-core
 libnginx-mod-mail
 nginx
 libnginx-mod-http-image-filter
 libnginx-mod-stream
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
~$ uname -r
5.18.12-051812-generic`

Comment: @user535733 I am just trying to find a simple answer to my problem. Don't leave a comment if you don't have an answer really simple.

Comment: @karel no doesnt work

Comment: It's encouraged to answer your own question to help future visitors, however it should be posted as an *answer*. Don't add the solution to your question. I've rolled back your edit but it's still in the [revision history](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1419366/5). Please add your solution as an answer.  Please also verify that the syntax and formatting are not ambiguous. Otherwise your answer can be difficult for other people to follow.  The solution you originally edited into your question was ambiguous. What is the exact line that needs to be added? Where? And and after what?

Comment: @Nmath I can post the answer tomorrow as it is 12 in the morning for me.

Answer (score 3):

I also got this issue recently. The exact error is the line

```
chown: invalid group: ‘root:adm’
```

Ubuntu doesn't have `adm` group by default. You can add the group adm manually.

```
sudo addgroup adm
```

Comment: @ArturMeinild I edit my answer to explain why we need to add the group.

Answer (score 0):

sudo groupadd adm

It worked for me when installing nginx. I then continued with the remaining installation that was halted before with an error with the command:

sudo apt install -f

Hope this helps.